How can I avoid millisecond delays in @Scheduled annotations?
I use @Scheduled in my work to implement some simple timed tasks,for example：
private static long  pre  = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000L)
    public void testScheduled() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        long cur = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long gap = cur - pre;
        pre = cur;
    }

Theoretically I think the value of gap should be 5000? .....
But in reality, he will have an error of a few milliseconds, or even a dozen milliseconds,I also tried scheduling with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, but the result was the same
I don't know enough about scheduled tasks, but I want to know what the reason is, please help me out!

Java is not a real-time language. There is no guarantee about the timings; the actual timing depends on many factors such as CPU speed, system load, memory pressure (e.g. swapping), JVM implementation (in particular GC), etc. Your mileage might vary, in practical terms one second accuracy should be OK most of the time, but anything less shouldn't be relied upon. Also, you cannot make assumptions about how much time Spring takes to initialize and start the timer.

Depending on the Spring Framework version you are using, precision is not guaranteed at the millisecond scale. Your computer internal clock can drift for various reasons; this means that scheduling the next task 5 seconds later might be correct, but the actual time when the execution happens might be different because of the internal clock.
As of Spring Framework 6.0.10, Spring provides nanosecond precision for several scheduling mechanisms.

Instead of just linking to a GitHub issue, could you show how to use the scheduling mechanisms with nanosecond precision? Or do you mean the existing mechanisms support nanosecond precision since that version which looks like it judging on this commit?

it looks like you have answered your own question.

I actually don't clear nanosecond schedules very well, and that's my problem.The description of the problem may not be clear, but in fact, the scheduled task may occur earlier or later, and there are mistakes.Can this be solved by nanosecond calls?

Have you tried upgrading to Spring Framework 6.0.10+? Also, please use System.nanoTime to measure time difference if you're looking for ns precision.
